# Delete matching line with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I currently have this sed command that replaces `foo.us.param=value` with `foo.param=value`:

```
sed -i -e 's/\.us\./\./' file.txt
```

I also need it to delete any lines that contain *.eu.* anywhere but leave all other lines untouched. Any help would save me a long time trying to figure this out alone and would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's/\.us\./\./' -e '/\.eu\./d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of sed you could also use grep

```
grep -v '\.eu\.'
```

Comment: `.` is a special regexp character it needs to be escaped.